# First time using eclipse today...and eclipse I really don't like it. What are some other alternatives that are cleaner?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

First time using eclipse today...and I really don't like it.  What are some other alternatives that are cleaner without a million buttons and multiple windows like eclipse has?
 Eclipse is so clunky and there are way too may options and buttons for myself.  Does anyone understand my problem and have a suggestion for another IDE I could use?  I don't understand how people can use eclipse and why it needs to be this cluttered.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives like `netbeans` etc.,

If you don't want so many buttons may be `notepad`, `Notepad++` (or) `EditPlus` etc., may help you, Note that these tools don't give you auto suggestions and other features.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse isn't all that bad once you get used to it. It's not all that cluttered and it implements a great deal of customization.

You could try NetBeans, but that's like jumping out of the frying pan straight into the fire.

Have you looked at IntelliJ?

Comment: no I have not.  I am just having a hard time getting around eclipse for the first time and its a bit frustrating :p ...Also I don't understand why my keywords in my code are not turning different colors...thanks

Comment: No actually its the other way around...there is no code highlighting...how do I turn this on?  Thanks!

Comment: Look under preferences > editor.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** One of the best feature which i liked is the `Perspective options`.... Like Java, DDMS,and many more...

**2.** Eclipse has some cool options, ya are in-fact in other IDE too, but i think its worth a mention...

`To format the code:` ctrl + shift + f

`To Import the packages:` ctrl + shift + o

etc................

**3.** Almost every 3rd partly open tools have `plugins` for Eclipse.... Audrino also has plugin for Eclipse..thats awesome....

Answer (score 0):

Other IDE's are [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/), [JCreator](http://www.jcreator.com/), [InteliIDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [Borland JBuilder](http://www.borland.com/default.aspx), [Dr. Java](http://drjava.sourceforge.net/), and your more simple notepad and notepad++